# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_admin' after installing firebase

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_admin'`  after installing firebase i.e. I've performed the following steps:

1. Open the console and install firebase via `pip3 install firebase-admin`. The requirements are already satisfied.
2. Running `pip3 show firebase-admin` outputs

   ```
   Name: firebase-admin
   Version: 6.2.0
   ...
   ```
3. Running `python` and inputting `import firebase_admin` gives `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'firebase_admin'`

---

What I've tried:

- Using `pip` as opposed to `pip3`.
- Reinstalling both `firebase` and `firebase-admin`.

Comment: Please show us the outputs of `which python`, `which pip` and `which pip3`

Comment: @LeonardoGazdek I'm confused, those are not commands. Do you mean for me to show which version of each I have installed?

Comment: I'd like to know where your python environment is getting loaded from. Seems like you are on Windows, right?

Comment: @LeonardoGazdek I am on Windows. Sorry for the silly question, but how can I show you where my python environment is getting loaded from?

Comment: Seems like you are installing `firebase-admin` in one environment and running the python file in another. Can you show how you are running the python file?

Comment: The `which` command in BaSH and other similar shells outputs the path to where the specified parameter is installed.  For example, `which ls` will output `/usr/bin/ls`.  On Windows you could use GitBash as your terminal shell instead of PowerShell or CMD, or you could use WSL.  Ultimately what Leonardo is suggesting is that you might have multiple versions of pip and python, so you might be installing in one version using pip/pip3 but running a different version with the `python` command.

Comment: Try executing `Get-Command python`, `Get-Command pip`, and `Get-Command pip3` in PowerShell.

Comment: @LeonardoGazdek @Sam `where` would be a loose equivalent on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. When I check the information, it have been installed in python 3.9 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wdXt.png)
Although I use python 3.11 as global

Update: I consulted the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536650/firebase-admin-sdk-with-flask-throws-error-no-module-named-firebase-admin) and it worked